# padding a select tag in haml

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

i've tried using `&nbsp;` but it keeps on adding double quotes which results to the html page literally printing out   in my html. Here is my sample code:

helper.rb

```
def available_options
  ["test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;", "test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;", "test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;"] 
end
```

and in my view:

```
= f.select, options_for_select(available_options)
```

is there a way to render this thing properly? I've tried raw and html_safe to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

html_safe should do the trick here, please try this in your helper.rb

```
def available_options
  ["test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;", 
   "test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;", 
   "test1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;test222&nbsp;"].map(&:html_safe) 
end
```

Comment: actually, html_safe was the culprit because it turns my &nbsp; into &amp;nbsp;

Comment: hmm worked for me exactly this example.. Anyway, check [this page](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/), probably it will help you

Comment: @alony : Come online here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-rails-enterprise-apps-developers